# Yii2 gridview filtering with dateRangePicker won't apply on input change

Tags: gridview, yii2

I've applied a datePeriodPicker to an input in Yii2 gridview filter row. It works but doesn't apply right after inserting value. You have to click the input again and press Enter. Other fields work fine. Is there any way I can make it apply just as other inputs, right after change?

Here's the script i used:

```
var 
    dateInput = $("[name='RequestSearch[request_date]']" ),
    configObject = {
        autoClose: true,
        language:'ru',
        separator: '/',
        showShortcuts : true,
        shortcuts: {
            'next-days': [3,5,7],
            'next': ['week','month','year']
        },
        startOfWeek: 'monday',
    };

dateInput.dateRangePicker(configObject);
```

**EDIT 1**

Here's the RequestSearch.php. dateRangePicker inserts values like "2015-01-05/2015-05-09" so I had to make a handler that divides the value into $start_date and $end_date.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'KP_id', 'minimal_payment', 'mover_company_id', 'manager_id', 'workers_number', 'workhours', 'payment_additional', 'payment_car', 'payment_sum'], 'integer'],
            [['request_date', 'payment_type', 'request', 'request_time', 'quantity', 'request_type', 'address', 'status', 'customer_id', 'comment',], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

 $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        ...

    ]);

    if ( ! is_null($this->request_date) && strpos($this->request_date, '/') !== false ) { 
        list($start_date, $end_date) = explode('/', $this->request_date);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'request_date', $start_date, $end_date]);
        $this->request_date = null;
    } else {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['request_date' => $this->request_date,]);
    }
```

Comment: Show me rules() function of RequestSearch Class may be `request_date` is not massively assigned in it

Comment: I think that's the expected behavior. If your filter is a textbox, the form will not be submitted until you actually submit it by hitting enter. Why should this custom input be any different? Try attaching a handler with `form.submit()` to `onChange` event of your `datePeriodPicker` input.

Comment: @Beowulfenator but other text field filters are applied right after changing their input. Hitting enter our clicking cursor out. .

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, they do. Then I guess your date field's `change` event has the proper handle but doesn't get fired because of some problem with your datepicker.

Comment: @Beowulfenator I've found solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the datepicker plugin I used inserted the input value using val() or something like that that doesn't trigger 'change' event that is needed for proper gridview filtering. Added .trigger('change') for the input and now it all works just fine. With the plugin I use here's the script that's working:

```
var dateInput = $("[name='RequestSearch[request_date]']");
dateInput.dateRangePicker();
dateInput.bind('datepicker-closed', function(){
    dateInput.trigger('change');
})
```